# Dynamic URL rewrite for search results

Tags: regex, apache, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Is there any option using **mod_rewrite** to dynamically rewrite URLs for search results?

I'm trying to fix URLs on my site to match Googles "seo friendly" policy.
I want to rewrite those URLS for 3 types of queries:

**a**) Location

> example.com/search-auto/?style1_nonce=6ac0625a27&location=**london**&autobrand=&automodel=&modelyear=&fueltype=&priceRange=540%2C43000&autotype=&searchauto=

to be:

example.com/search-auto/**london**/

where **london** can be any location based on user search.

**b**) Location + brand:

> example.com/search-auto/?style1_nonce=6ac0625a27&location=**london**&autobrand=**bmw**&automodel=&modelyear=&fueltype=&priceRange=540%2C43000&autotype=&searchauto=

to be: example.com/search-auto/**london**/**bmw**/

where **london** and **bmw** can be any location/brand based on user search.

**c**) Location + brand + model:

> example.com/search-auto/?style1_nonce=6ac0625a27&location=**londo**n&autobrand=**bmw**&automodel=**BMW+1+SERIES**&modelyear=&fueltype=&priceRange=540%2C43000&autotype=&searchauto=

to be: example.com/search-auto/**london**/**bmw**/**bmw+1+series**/

where **london**, **bmw** and **bmw 1 series** can be any location/brand/model based on user search.

**Please note**:
I know that I can use a "static" instructions, e.g.:

```
# Rewrite --- https://example.com/search-auto/?style1_nonce=6ac0625a27&location=london&autobrand=audi&automodel=audi+a1&modelyear=&fueltype=&priceRange=540%2C43000&autotype=&searchauto= => https://example.com/search-auto/london/audi/audi+a1/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)style1_nonce\=6ac0625a27($|&)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)location\=london($|&)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)autobrand\=audi($|&)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)automodel\=audi\+a1($|&)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)modelyear\=($|&)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)fueltype\=($|&)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)priceRange\=540%2C43000($|&)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)autotype\=($|&)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)searchauto\=($|&)
RewriteRule ^search\-auto/$ /search-auto/london/audi/audi+a1/?&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

but style1_nonce=**6ac0625a27** is for each user different so I'm unable create a bulk list of rewrite instructions for all URLs.
Is there any hope for me?

Cheeers, Kris

Comment: Nice URLs are pretty for human reading, however, they do not have any advantage for SEO purposes. `?location=london&autobrand=AUDI&automodel=A4&modelyear=&2006` already **is** SEO-friendly, more than `/london/AUDI/A4/2006`. Search engines do know how to read parameters, and a parameter name is an additional information to them. We have arrived in the year 2019. **Not** SEO-friendly is `?location=23&autobrand=127&model=63`

Comment: You should spend more time on building a sitemap and allowing/disallowing taking particular pages into the index, propery style your page in a responsive way (google likes that) and most important: take care of the *content* emphasing important keywords.